# Join tables with foreign key relationship

Tags: magento2, collection, uicomponent

I wrote an admin module with a form, which consists of a text area and a dynamic-row form component.

My data is split up in two custom tables with a FK/PK relationship.

I need to populate my form component with this data, so I performed a table join inside my collection class.

```
    $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['secondTable' => $this->getTable('calcengine_calcparams')],
            'main_table.Calc_id = secondTable.MyCalc_id',
            array('*')
        );
```

Next in my DataProvider I tried to recieve this data.

```
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

  ...

  public function getData()
  {
        if (isset($this->_loadedData)) {
            return $this->_loadedData;
        }

        $items = $this->collection->getItems();

        ...
  }

}
```

But I'll always recieve this error:

> Item (Vendor\Module\Model\Calcforms) with the same ID "11" already exists.

Does anybody have an idea how to populate my form with a joined table?

Comment: is MyCalc_id have multiple ids ? like 11 is for twice ?

Comment: you are trying to join table which has one to many relation. use left join instead

Comment: @MineshPatel Using joinLeft instead of join does not make a difference.

Comment: @ManthanDave Yes MyCalc_id (FK in secondary table and PK in main table) can have a id twice, because one table contains parameters, the other calculations, one calculation can have multiple parameters (1:n relationship)

Comment: @TrytoFly yes thats why you are getting this error . Because how would you display that multiple records in one form ? Do one thing Group by this MyCalc_id and then check it will works

Comment: @TrytoFly i forgot to mansion "Magento Collection doesn't allow  collection with duplicate value"

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581429/magento-allow-duplicate-products-in-collection) this is for magento 1.x but same should apply for magento2

Comment: @MineshPatel Thank you for the link! So I basically have to overwrite the core files? I would have hoped I did not have to do that. ^^"

Comment: @ManthanDave Well, my train of thought was to get all the parameters linked to a calculation and populate my dynamic-rows component, I don't know if there is a better alternative due to the lack of documentation.

Comment: is it necessary to use collection ? you can not achieve this by custom query on resource model ?

Comment: @MineshPatel Potentially, I still have to think my way through magento from examples I observed I thought, collections are supposed to be what fetches the right data from the db for my DataProvider to use. But i guess I could try to use the afterLoad hook to add the data from the second table!

Comment: @MineshPatel Well ok, that did not work, the _afterLoad method (who knew) does of course get triggered after the data is loaded, to populate my form, I would need to overwrite a method that gets triggered earlier.